# Ruby on Rails: What is a good method to draw dynamic ascii art?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-canvas, ascii

I want to make an app that displays binary trees as ascii. A user would be able to start as a root node, and choose to create a node left or right. At any point the user can  go back up to the parent node and travel down a different branch of the tree to create more nodes. From an OOP perspective this is quite easy, I am having trouble creating this graphically though.

I was thinking of making this work by having variables hold a string which represent left and right nodes in ascii. Say a user was on the root node, and they tried to create a left node, then the left_node string would append itself to root.

The problem with this is:

How do I 'save' the position of the root node, from which to append the left_node? Is this a good approach? Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: In a sentence, what exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a node-object that holds all the information. For example, a simple object could look like this:

```
function TreeNode(parent, text, x, y) {
    this.parent = parent;                 // if null then this is the root
    this.text = text || 'node';
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0
}
```

Now you can create a tree by assigning the node to the previous node and/or parent:

```
var tree = [];

var root = new TreeNode(null, "Root", 50, 50);
var nodeLeft = new TreeNode(root, "Left", 50, 50);
var nodeRight = new TreeNode(root, "Right", 50, 50);
```

And so on (you will probably want a visual editing approach to this). Push them to your array in any order (the parent reference keeps track of connections).

The simply iterate over your array twice, one to draw connections between two nodes, the second time to draw the node on top (by being more accurate with the connection lines you can get away with one loop - I didn't do that for this example).

Please see source code below for more details and a live demo:

```js
// node object
function TreeNode(parent, text, x, y) {
    this.parent = parent || null;  // if null then this is the root
    this.text = text || 'node';
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0
}

// get canvas context
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// holds all the nodes
var tree = [];

// some example nodes
var root = new TreeNode(null, "Root", 250, 140);

// childen of root node
var nodeLeft = new TreeNode(root, "Left", 140, 85);
var nodeRight = new TreeNode(root, "Right", 360, 85);

// children of left node
var nodeLeftL = new TreeNode(nodeLeft, "Left to left", 70, 30);
var nodeLeftR = new TreeNode(nodeLeft, "Right to left", 220, 30);

// store all nodes in array
tree.push(root, nodeLeft, nodeRight, nodeLeftL, nodeLeftR);

// RENDER

// connections
for(var i = 0; node = tree[i]; i++) {
    renderLine(node, node.parent);
}

// nodes
for(var i = 0; node = tree[i]; i++) {
    renderNode(node);
}

// here is the canvas graphics functions:

// render a line between any two nodes:
function renderLine(n1, n2){

    // check that we actually have two nodes as one could
    // be the root node (root of course doesn't have a parent)
    if (n1 && n2) {

      // knock yourselves out artistically...
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;

      // the line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(n1.x, n1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(n2.x, n2.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
}

// render the node itself
function renderNode(node){
    ctx.font = 'bold 14px monospace';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

    ctx.fillStyle = '#555';
    ctx.fillText('.---------------.', node.x, node.y - 14);
    ctx.fillText(node.text, node.x, node.y);
    ctx.fillText('|               |', node.x, node.y);
    ctx.fillText('---------------', node.x, node.y + 14);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: This is BEYOND awesome. Thanks Ken. I will implement this